# Not reproducible exe hang of Matlab Compiler output executable

Tags: debugging, matlab, matlab-deployment

I have the following problem:
I have a Matlab program in form of some set of *.m files. It is later compiled into executable and used. The problem is that occasionally the resulted executable just hangs and this behavior cannot be reproduced when debugging/running *.m files from IDE (even using the same input data).

To figure out what hapens I intended to:

- compile (somehow) *.m files into C/C++
- compile C/C++ as debug to get .exe and .pdb
  And later when .exe hangs just 'attach' visual studio debugger to hanged .exe to check where it 'loops/waits'.

Unfortunaley Matlab Compiler (as I was told today) does not produce C/C++ code before creating executable. I was misleaded by ***-g*** option of ***mcc*** which according to the documenttion is supposed to do the following:

```
-g Generate Debugging Information

Include debugging symbol information for the C/C++ code generated by MATLAB Compiler.
```

It looks exacly like the thing I want to archive.
I would appreciate if someone could explain me that discapency or suggest how to archive what I am trying to do (if it can be done at all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to create a debuggable code in Matlab compiler, because the deployed code uses MCR. (Matlab virtual machine) .

See this question : [Is there any way to debug compiled components using Matlab Debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553559/is-there-any-way-to-debug-compiled-components-using-matlab-debugger)

Since you don't have errors, but rather an infinite loop, the best solution in that case would be screen outputs, and hopefully you will trace the bug.