# Debug MATLAB functions called from a JAVA program

Tags: java, matlab, matlab-deployment

So I have a jar built with the MATLAB Builder JA tool. Is it possible to debug the MATLAB functions from the Java process using the jar file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to debug compiled components using Matlab Debugger?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553559/is-there-any-way-to-debug-compiled-components-using-matlab-debugger)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't debug them in the sense of being able to step through the MATLAB code line by line, as you can with MATLAB's own debugger prior to compilation. One of the steps that the MATLAB deployment products take is to encrypt the MATLAB code (so you can preserve your IP when distributing the deployed component). The ability to step through the code in a debugger after deployment would defeat the purpose of that.

Typically you would want to debug in MATLAB before deployment, or perhaps spread some `disp`  statements around your code in a way that can be turned off after deployment (sorry if that advice doesn't help you now that have a .jar file).